# Maven compilation error while installation

Tags: maven

COMPILATION ERROR :

```
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.3/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar; error in opening zip file
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project edvie-ws-core: Compilation failure
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.3/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Comment: How to fix the above problem any suggessions

Comment: do you have the permission to read that file?

Comment: You should post the full error output and not only excerpts.

Comment: yes in linux i know to give permission @ Drogba

Comment: @user3278325:Drogba is just trying to solve your problem. And looking at your exception that is most valid reason. Check if your jar is not corrupted. If possible, try recreating .m2 repo.

Comment: tried all the possible way like deletion, creation and giving permissions

Comment: Delete /root/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.3 and do mvn clean install -U

Comment: @user3278325 - any luck?

Comment: Can you provide complete stacktrace or run mvn command with -X flag.

Comment: yes done by using artifact and maven command